# What does the error cannot be resolved or is not a field mean?

Tags: java, tree, field

So I am writing a code for a binary search tree and I am far(I think) and there is a point where when I try and compile it I get an error that says

"File: D:\ReservationQueue.java  [line: 15]

Error: left cannot be resolved or is not a field

File: D:\ReservationQueue.java  [line: 17]

Error: right cannot be resolved or is not a field

File: D:\ReservationQueue.java  [line: 4]
Warning: The field ReservationQueue.right is never read locally...

this is the code for the errors,

```
public class ReservationQueue{
private Reservation root;
private Reservation left;
private Reservation right;

public boolean empty() {return root == null;}
public String findRoot() {return root.getName();}
public void deleteRoot(){root = left; }

public void insert(Reservation node) {

if(this.empty()) {
  root = node;
} else if (node.getPriority() < root.getPriority()){
  insert(node.left);
} else if (node.getPriority() > root.getPriority()){
  insert(node.right);
}
}
}
```

This is the Reservation class if it helps
    public class Reservation{
    private int priority;
    private String name;

```
public Reservation(String name, int priority){
 if (priority < 1) {
 this.priority = 1;
} else if (priority > 10) {
 this.priority = 10;
} else {
 this.priority = priority;
}
}
public String getName(){return name;}
public int getPriority(){return priority;}
}
```

I really need help I have no idea what I am doing wrong, thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

`node` is type `Reservation`, and `left` and `right` are fields of `ReservationQueue`. Therefore the following two lines won't compile:

```
insert(node.left);
insert(node.right);
```

If `ReservationQueue` is meant to be a tree with nodes of type `Reservation`, then `left` and `right` should probably be members of `Reservation` and not of `ReservationQueue`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not totally clear what you are doing.

1. You don't have left and right variables in Reservetion classs, and what are they anyways.
2. May be you mean to

   ```
   else if (node.getPriority() < root.getPriority()){
        insert(left);
    } else if (node.getPriority() > root.getPriority()){
       insert(right);
   ```